# BindingName does not work in Azure Event Hub Trigger

Tags: java, azure, triggers, binding

I have the following event hub trigger, implemented in Java:

```html
    @FunctionName("eventHubHandler")
    public String execute(@EventHubTrigger(name = "msg",
            eventHubName = "commands",
            connection = "eventhub_connection") String message,
            @BindingName("Properties") Map<String, Object> properties,
            final ExecutionContext context
    ) {

        return "result";
    }
```

According to the Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=java) the @BindingName annotation should bind the message headers to the properties parameter.

When I try to run it local development environment with "mvn azure-functions:run", and I send a message to the event hub, I got the following exception:

```
Exception: NullPointerException:
Stack: java.lang.NullPointerException
[2022-03-01T01:02:00.567Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.binding.BindingDataStore.getTriggerMetatDataByName(BindingDataStore.java:59)
[2022-03-01T01:02:00.567Z]      at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.ParameterResolver.resolve(ParameterResolver.java:62)
```

[2022-03-01T01:02:00.568Z]      at

I checked the code of BindingDataStore, and it seems to be unable to find the metadata with the name "Property"

```
public Optional<BindingData> getTriggerMetatDataByName(String name, Type target) {      
    return this.metadataSources.get(name).computeByName(name, target);
}
```

The same error comes for the key SystemProperties as well. Any idea, how the binding should work?

Comment: Same issue perhaps? https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/issues/293